# Oracle - getting row numbers for a group

Tags: oracle, count, row, grouping

I have the SQL below which Im using to get row numbers. What I want is to know how many rows are in a particular group. Is this possible?

Thanks

```
   select 
          to_char(ndt.dt , 'yyyy'), 
          to_char(ndt.dt , 'MON'), 
          to_char(ndt.dt , 'dd'),  
          row_number() OVER (partition by to_char(ndt.dt , 'yyyy'), to_char(ndt.dt , 'MON') ORDER BY ndt.dt)    

          from (
            (SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM + 44) dt
             FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 91
             order by dt asc) ndt
          );
```

but this gives me

1. |2016|   APR |01|    1|
2. |2016|   APR |02|    2|
3. ...
4. |2016|   APR|30| 30|
5. |2016|MAY|   01  |1|
6. |2016|   MAY |

whereas what I really want is

1. |2016|   APR |01|    30|
2. |2016|   APR |02|    30|
3. ...
4. |2016|   APR|30| 30|
5. |2016|MAY|   01  |31|
6. |2016|   MAY |31|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this, using `count` instead or `row_number`:

```
select to_char(d, 'yyyy'), to_char(d, 'mon'), to_char(d, 'dd'),
       count(1) over ( partition by extract(month from d)) as count
from (
        select to_date('01042016', 'ddmmyyyy') + level -1 as d
        from dual
        connect by level <= 61
     )
order by 1, 2, 3
```

The logics behind your +44 is not that clear to me, so I used a simple starting date

Comment: thanks @Aleksej The 44 was to offset my days. I should have removed this from the code sample